# Creating a matrix with complex numbers

Tags: java, matrix, complex-numbers

I'm trying to create a matrix with complex numbers in Java. After compiling, the program memorizes in every v[i][j] only the last readen real resp. imaginary part..I think this has to do with the warning "The static field Matrix.im(/Matrix.re) should be accessed in a static way", but I don't really know what this means..I'm kinda new into Java, what do I do wrong? Thanks! ^-^

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    public class Matrix {
    public static double im,re;

    public Matrix(double re, double im)
    {
        this.re=re;
        this.im=im;
    }


        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            int n,m,i,j;
            double x,y;
            Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
            n=sc.nextInt();
            m=sc.nextInt();
            Matrix[][] v= new Matrix[n][m];
            for(i=0;i<n;i++)
                for(j=0;j<m;j++)
                    {
                        x=sc.nextDouble();
                        y=sc.nextDouble();
                        v[i][j]=new Matrix(x,y);
                }
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<m;j++)
                System.out.print(v[i][j].re+"+i*"+v[i][j].im+" ");
            System.out.println();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your question, it is very confusing what exactly you are asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've shot yourself in the foot with your static fields. Change this:

```
public static double im,re;
```

to this:

```
public double im,re;
```

Or better:

```
private double im,re;
```

With appropriate getters and possibly setters if the class is mutable.

Please note that static fields are fields of the **class** not the instance, and so every Matrix instance will hold the same values for these fields **unless** you make the instance (non-static) fields.